# How do I sync entries from multiple columns on google sheets to the description box on google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I am currently working off a script that generates a calendar event from a google sheet line entry. My issue is I am not able to add entries from more than one column to the description field on my calendar. The following code assumes I only want one column to be used in the entry of a description field. How do I modify this so that I can include another column's data into the description field of a google calendar entry?

```
//insert your google calendar ID
var calendarId = "mygmailcalendar.com";

//index (starting from 1) of each column in the sheet
var titleIndex = 2;
var descriptionIndex = 3;
var startDateIndex = 4;
var endDateIndex = 5;
var googleCalendarIndex = 6;

/*
find the row where the Google Calendar Event ID is blank or null
The data of this row will be used to create a new calendar event
*/
function findRow(sheet) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
 var values = dataRange.getValues();

 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 if(values[i][googleCalendarIndex-1]=="" || values[i][googleCalendarIndex-1]==null)
 newEvent(i+1);
 } 
 };


/* 
get the data of the new row by calling getSheetData() and 
create a new Calendar event by calling submitToGoogleCalendar()
*/

function newEvent(row){ 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var eventId = submitToGoogleCalendar(getSheetData(sheet,row),null)
 if(eventId!=null) 
 sheet.getRange(row,googleCalendarIndex,1,1).setValue(eventId);
};


/* 
Store the data of a row in an Array
*/

function getSheetData(sheet,row)
{
 var data = new Array();

 data.title=sheet.getRange(row,titleIndex,1,1).getValue();
 data.description=sheet.getRange(row,descriptionIndex,1,1).getValue();

 data.startDate = sheet.getRange(row,startDateIndex,1,1).getValue();
 data.endDate = sheet.getRange(row,endDateIndex,1,1).getValue();

 return data; 
};

/* 
if a cell is edited in the sheet, get all the data of the corresponding row and 
create a new calendar event (after deleting the old event) by calling submitToGoogleCalendar() 
*/

function dataChanged(event){

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var row = event.range.getRow();

 var eventId = sheet.getRange(row,googleCalendarIndex,1,1).getValue();

 var eventId = submitToGoogleCalendar(getSheetData(sheet,row),eventId)

 if(eventId!=null)
 sheet.getRange(row,googleCalendarIndex,1,1).setValue(eventId);

};


/* 
This function creates an event in the Google Calendar and returns the calendar event ID 
which is stored in the last column of the sheet 
*/
function submitToGoogleCalendar(sheetData,eventId) {
 // some simple validations ;-)
 if(sheetData.title == "" || sheetData.startDate == "" || sheetData.startDate == null)
 return null;

 var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
 var start = new Date(sheetData.startDate);
 var end = new Date(sheetData.endDate);
 //end.setHours(23);
//end.setMinutes(59);
 //end.setSeconds(59);

 // some simple date validations
 if(start > end)
 return null;

 var event = null;

 //if eventId is null (when called by newEvent()) create a new calendar event
 if(eventId==null)
 {
 event = cal.createEvent(sheetData.title, start, end, {
 description : sheetData.description, 
 });
 return event.getId(); 
 }
 /*
 else if the eventid is not null (when called by dataChanged()), delete the calendar event 
 and create a new event with the modified data by calling this function again
 */
 else
 {
 event = cal.getEventSeriesById(eventId);
 event.deleteEventSeries(); 
 return submitToGoogleCalendar(sheetData,null);
 }

 return event.getId();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot populate the event description from two columns in an event export script as far as I'm aware.
You can however join multiple columns into the column you are exporting as the description column quite easily quite a few methods including formulas and scripts. For example :

> =ARRAYFORMULA(L7:L&""&AL7:AL)